# What do you get when you level after you have already reached level 80?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have finally reached level 80 in Guild Wars 2 and I figured since that was the max level, my exp bar would just be perpetually filled and I wouldn't glow when I level. However that is not the case. It still shows the progress for when I "level" next and I still get that leveling glow.

Below level 80, you get one trait point and one skill point for leveling. Do you get anything for leveling after you are already level 80?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Guild Wars 2 Digital Strategy Guide:

> Even after reaching level 80, your hero learns more about him- or
>   herself and about the world. Experience at that lofty height still
>   goes onto your bar, eventually leading to new “levels” that grant free
>   skill points. You won’t rise above the level cap, but these points let
>   you learn new skills or buy items that are used with the powerful
>   mystic forge recipes.

Comment: This is a behaviour similar to Guild Wars 1, where you always got experience, even at maximum level. Each new "level up" would grant you a skill point, so eventually you could learn all skills available.