# Is it normal to continue levelling after reaching the level cap?

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you get when you level after you have already reached level 80?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82523/what-do-you-get-when-you-level-after-you-have-already-reached-level-80)

I have reached level 80, but I have noticed I am still getting experience. In addition to getting experience, I still seem to reach the 'new level' threshold, get the character animation and the voice prompt with the big splash. After this happens my experience bar resets, like I have just got a new level, and continues counting.

Is it normal to continue levelling after reaching the level cap?

What is happening? Is there any benefit from continuing to grind experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to continue leveling!

Once you hit level 80, you will continue to gain XP. Every time you level after (254,000 XP), you will gain a Skill Point! These [skill points](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skill_point) can be used as currency for purchasing [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge) crafting items from [Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani) in Lion's Arch.